# How to add using the 'with' keyword?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

```
public record Cube(int x, int y, int z, int w);
```

I recently ran across a time I was doing this:

```
var next = new Cube(existing.x + 1, existing.y, existing.z, existing.w);
```

and I thought there must be a cleaner way to add arbitrary values to the record. But when I try this:

```
var next = existing with { x = x+1 };
```

It cries because you do not have access to the values to add to. Instead I have to do this:

```
var next = existing with { x = existing.x+1 };
```

Am I just wanting too much from the `with` keyword?

Comment: Consider this: if you had a local variable by the name of `x`, how would you reference it if the `x` in `x + 1` meant the existing `x` property? You can't qualify it with anything to make it use the local instead of the property.

Comment: My AoC looked exactly the same (before switching to value tuples) . Except I had the "neighbors" as a member function, so it looked like `this with { X=X+1 }` though then an IDE bug suggested `X+=1` which is obviously invalid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My understanding of with syntax is exactly that - you must reference the name of the object to the left of the width statement. This seems to line up with the spec here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/records

While the `x = x + 1` is convenient, it is not very expressive on the source of where x is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

The x in `x = x+1` is the x of the next instance to be created. However, this instance does not yet exist at that point that's why the compiler complains. Instead, you have to state explicitly that the second x is the one of the existing instance.